# Libros recomendados sobre la historia de la lengua española

Tags: historia, recursos

Estoy buscando una recomendación de un buen libro sobre la historia de la lengua española. No soy filólogo, por tanto no creo que un texto académico sea adecuado. Aún así, me gustaría algo riguroso, algo completo (libros demasiado "amenos" resultan, frecuentemente, ser un poco aburridos)

Me parece interesante, por ejemplo, "Historia de la lengua española" de Lapesa, y me gustaría comprarlo, pero es un poco más encima de mi nivel, con tanto detalle, que no sé si lo completara.  Similarmente, "gramática histórica" de Penny parece ser demasiado.  "La maravillosa historia del español" del instituto Cervantes me parece un poco bajo de lo que estoy buscando (aunque parece interesante). ¿Qué pensais de "Los 1001 años de la lengua española" de Alatorre?  Me parece que ocupa un lugar intermediario, pero no sé cómo valorarlo.

Comment: He pedido este libro de mi biblioteca, pero no lo tengo todavía. Luego te podré dar una opinión. Gente de Cervantes : historia humana del idioma español
Lodares, Juan R. 2001

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo ["Breve historia de la lengua española" de Pharies](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01APAAAEK/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_hsch_vapi_tkin_p1_i0); la última versión es de 2015. Además, si te apetece la etimología, fíjate a [los libros de Ortega Pérez](https://smile.amazon.com/Virgilio-Ortega-P%C3%A9rez/e/B00LCT1U4S/ref=dp_byline_cont_pop_ebooks_1).